# How to get the mean of array each time it's filled?

Tags: python, arrays, list, statistics

I'm trying to write in a file .txt in two distinct columns, one for the date/time and the other one for the mean of 100 data values changing continuously in an infinite loop, the initial code works, before i tried to calculate the mean, here is my code

```
import serial
import time
import datetime as dt
ser = serial.Serial('COM23', 19200)

with open("data101.txt", "w+") as f:
    for i in range(100):  
       serial_line = ser.readline()
       fl = float(serial_line)
       print(fl)
       f.write("{} {} {}\n".format(i+1, dt.datetime.now(), fl))
       time.sleep(0.000033)

ser.close()
```

But when I'm adding the array/list and try to get the mean of each 100 values it won't work, here is my code

```
import numpy       # i added numpy library  
import serial
import time
import datetime as dt
ser = serial.Serial('COM23', 19200)

with open("data102.txt", "w+") as f:
    for i in range(100):  
       serial_line = ser.readline()
       fl = float(serial_line)
       f = []                        # i added this to create an empty array 
           for i in range(100):
              f.append(fl)
              print(numpy.mean(f))          # i added this
              array = numpy.mean(f)         # i added this
              print(fl)
              f.write("{} {} {}\n".format(i+1, dt.datetime.now(), array))
              time.sleep(0.000033)

ser.close()
```

I would like to get the date/time in a column and every time the array is filled i calculate the mean and write it in the file at the seconde column.

Given that the amount of data is huge should i use sql library ? or any suitable functions ?

Comment: Please fix your indents

Comment: @StephenRauch here you go it's fixed didn't see it sorry

Comment: @Squide To avoid infinite loop you should replace second `for i` by `for j`

Comment: @Nuageux i did it and i still get the same error  : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'  ,and what i would like to do is to get an infinite loop  ( its because I want to receive the value of my pressure sensor continuously )